# Azure Api Management - Trace not available despite sub keys and trace set to true

Tags: azure, api, azure-api-management, ibm-api-management

The trace tab always says:

```
Trace location was not specified in the response or trace log is not available.
```

This is despite me passing both an **Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key** and **Ocp-Apim-Trace** in the headers as described in the docs (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-advanced-policies#Trace).

Yes, my subscription key is tied to an admin account of the Api-m instance. The key, however, is tied to a product which holds the underlying Api. Does that make any difference?

Anyone else encountered this issue?

Comment: Does response have ocp-apim-trace-location header?

Comment: Check this please https://github.com/uglide/azure-content/blob/master/articles/api-management/api-management-howto-api-inspector.md

Answer (score 0):

The subscription key of the product that is associated with this API that the developer can use the keys in it to access all APIs in the product.

API Inspector traces are only generated and made available for requests containing subscription keys that belong to the administrator account.

You can get the admin subscription key in `Developer Portal` -> `Profile` -> find your API and subscription key.

In the response headers will be an `ocp-apim-trace-location`, for more details you could refer to this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-howto-api-inspector).